# Async tasks are evaluated twice

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I use the following method to do some tasks asynchronously and at the same time:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(string[] queries)
{
    var results = queries.Select(query => new Tuple<string, Task<object>>(query, LoadDataAsync(query)));

    await Task.WhenAll(results.Select(x => x.Item2).ToArray());

    return results
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2.Result);
}
```

I want the method to call `LoadDataAsync` for each string in the array at the same time, then wait until all tasks are finished and return the result.

- If I run the method like this, it invokes `LoadDataAsync` twice for each item, once at the `await ...` line, and once at the final `.Result` property getter.
- If I remove the `await ...` line, Visual Studio warns me that the whole method would run in parallel, since there are not `await` calls inside of the method.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Are there better (shorter) ways to do the same?**

Comment: Well, of course they are - you're enumerating the `results` query twice. If you use `queries...ToArray()` first, it will work. You're enumerating `queries` twice, doing a new `LoadDataAsync` each time.

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your code example. The array `items` is ignored and a mysterious global variable called `queries` is used. Did you post an incompletely edited code sample?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Corrected it. Shouldn't be doing code edits inside SO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Once again:

**If I could teach people one thing about LINQ it would be that the value of a query is an object that executes the query, not the results of executing the query**.

You create the query once, producing an object which can execute the query. You then execute the query twice. You have unfortunately created a query that not only computes a value but produces a side effect, and therefore, executing the query twice produces the side effect twice. **Do not make reusable query objects that produce side effects, ever**.  Queries are a mechanism for *asking questions*, hence their name. They are not intended to be a control flow mechanism, but that's what you're using them for.

Executing the query twice produces two different results because of course *the results of the query could have changed between the two executions*. If the query is querying a database, say, the database could have changed between executions. If your query is "what are all the last names of every customer in London?" the answer could *change* from millisecond to millisecond, but the *question* stays the same. Always remember, the query represents *a question*.

I would be inclined to write something without queries. Use "foreach" loops to create side effects.

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(IEnumerable<string> queries)
{
    var tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task<object>>();
    foreach (string query in queries)
        tasks.Add(query, LoadDataAsync(query));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Values);
    return tasks.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to remember that LINQ operations return queries, not the results of those queries.  The variable `results` doesn't represent the results of the operation that you have, but rather *a query that is able to generate those results when iterated*.  You iterate it twice, executing the query on each of those occasions.

What you can do here is materialize the results of the query into a collection first, rather than storing the query itself, in `results`.

```
var results = queries.Select(query => Tuple.Create(query, LoadDataAsync(query)))
    .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(results.Select(x => x.Item2));

return results
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2.Result);
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way might be to format the async calls in such a way that the results of the tasks are returned by the await with their respective keys:

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, object>> LoadNamedResultAsync(string query)
{
    object result = null;
    // Async query setting result 
    return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(query, result)
}

public async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> Read(string[] queries)
{
    var tasks = queries.Select(LoadNamedResultAsync);
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to [Jesse Sweetland's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395328/jesse-sweetland) answer, the fully implemented version:

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, object>> LoadNamedResultAsync(string query)
{
    Task<object> getLoadDataTask = await LoadDataAsync(query);
    return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(query, getLoadDataTask.Result);
}

public async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> Read(string[] queries)
{
    var tasks = queries.Select(LoadNamedResultAsync);
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
}
```

*Rem: I proposed this as edit but it was rejected because of too much changes.*