# Why async functions are called twice?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm using Threading timer to do some periodic job:

```
private static async void TimerCallback(object state)
{
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);
        var tasksRecord = tasksRead.Where(x => x.Result != null).Select(x => RecordReadingAsync(x.Result));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksRecord);

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount);
}
```

I made timer call back `async` and used `WhenAll`. In each working async function I have one Console output, which shows activity. Now the problem is that on second timer event each async function is working twice for some reason. The timer is set to long period. The application is Windows Console type. Is it `Select` that somehow make it run twice?

Comment: Try add `ToArray` after first `Select(i => ReadSensors)` you may be enumerating enumerable twice once in `WhenAll` and second time in `tashsRead.Where`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async tasks are evaluated twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124676/async-tasks-are-evaluated-twice)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));
```

creates a lazily evaluated IEnumerable which maps numbers to method invocation results. `ReadSensorsAsync` is not invoked here, it *will* be invoked during evaluation.

This IEnumerable is evaluated twice. Here:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);
```

and here:

```
// Here, another lazy IEnumerable is created based on tasksRead.
var tasksRecord = tasksRead.Where(...).Select(...);  
await Task.WhenAll(tasksRecord);  // Here, it is evaluated.
```

Thus, `ReadSensorsAsync` is invoked twice.

---

As csharpfolk suggested in the comments, materializing the IEnumerable should fix this:

```
var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: So in `await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead)` it starting to evaluate and because the method is awaitable, then next statement is evaluated, where the function is invoked in parallel to the invocations before. Is it right? Do I understand correctly, that ToList will make things synchronous and then WhenAll will not make sense any more?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with asynchronity! Let's consider a simple synchronous example: `int i1 = tasksRead.Count(); int i2 = tasksRead.Count(); int i3 = tasksRead.Count();` will execute ReadSensorsAsync three times.

Comment: If it helps, you can think of `taskReads` as a *function* that creates the list of sensor readings rather than the result of the sensor readings. If you "call" it multiple times, it will be executed multiple times.

Comment: Instead of using a `.ToList()`, this could also be fixed by using the `T[]` returned by `await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);` for the following `.Where(` instead of using `tasksRead` a 2nd time. Also, technically, the 2nd spot it gets used is not the `tasksRead.Where(` it is the `await Task.WhenAll(tasksRecord);` because the `.Where(` is lazily evaluated too just like the first part.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: How could I miss that? Thanks, I have added this to my answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Oh, you've added your own! +1 to you, and revert of mine. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Task.WhenAll` on a `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` it will return a `T[]` of the completed Tasks results. You need to save that variable and use it or else you will end up with the multiple enumerations like [Henzi mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37627511/80274).

Here is a solution without the unnecessarily calling of `.ToList()`

```
private static async void TimerCallback(object state)
{
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));
        var finshedTasks = await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);
        var tasksRecord = finshedTasks.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => RecordReadingAsync(x));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksRecord);

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentlyRunningTasksCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know WHY !
In two words: - reason that function with await impliciti create a callback thread. Better you can see how explain it Jeffrey Richter on this video https://wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=performing-i-o-bound-asynchronous-operations from 00:17:25

just try it:

```
var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => ReadSensorsAsync(i));
var tasksRecord = tasksRead.Where(x => x.Result != null).Select(x => RecordReadingAsync(x.Result));

await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);

await Task.WhenAll(tasksRecord);
```