# Passing exception from Task.Run to await properly and Debugger

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

This is the task, where the exception is being thrown.

```
public Task<SensorReading> ReadSensorsAsync(int cell)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
...
```

This is the `async` method:

```
private async void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    try
    {
        var tasksRead = Enumerable.Range(3, 35).Select(i => sensorReader.ReadSensorsAsync(i)).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);
        var r = tasksRead.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
        var taskRecordREsult = RecordReadingAsync(r).Result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // expecting to catch everything here
    }
}
```

What I was expecting is that exception would be handled in `await` part of the code. However, I am getting unhandled exception in Visual Studio debugger.

Question - how to properly pass all kind of exception from `Task.Run` to awaitable part?

Comment: If you hit "continue", did it *then* get caught? That's what I've seen very often...

Comment: btw can you include the "await" expression in the example?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, "continue" takes me to the await, but I don't want VS to tell me that I have "unhandled exception" every time something happens in `Task.Run`.

Comment: @alexm: I've updated the code

Comment: So the title of "unable to pass exception from Task.Run to await" is a bit inaccurate... it's really "Debugger annoyingly breaking when exception is thrown from task"

Comment: I suspect https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/ would help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've updated the tile. Hope technically I am doing this correctly in the code I provided.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `RecordReadingAsync(r).Result` is a bad idea, you can end up deadlocking your program. you should make it `await RecordReadingAsync(r)` instead. The function is already async so it will not be any extra work to convert it. Also `var r = tasksRead.Select(x => x.Result).ToList()` is redundant. just change the previous line to `var r = await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead);`, it gives you a array instead of a list, but if you really need a list you could call `.ToList()` on it too.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Do I understand correctly that for this particular case with `Task`s I have to go through each possible exception that can be thrown and do "continue when unhandled..."?

Comment: @Pablo: I suspect you can just do it for `AggregateException`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: didn't work. still VS breaking the code on exception.

Comment: Okay, well I'm afraid I don't have time to investigate it right now... I'm surprised that doesn't work though.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: For redundant part I had problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627393/why-async-functions-are-called-twice. For `await`, you are right.

Comment: @Pablo the answer you where given overlooked the fact that `Task.WhenAll<TResult>(` returns a `Task<TResult[]>`, you only needed to save the returned value and use it, you didn't need to do a 2nd select.

Comment: @JonSkeet: no worries. The bad part is that sometimes there are exceptions in Task.Run, which are first handled by the await part, but then generating unhandled exception. This is when running applitation without debugger.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks indeed, I'm going to work that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to extract your Task.Run lambda into a standalone method, and add the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute to it.  In theory (I haven't tested this), this will suppress the first exception in the debugger, and allow it to be caught later.  It's not pretty, but it should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is not only debugger itself, but also handling deeper exceptions. So the first question still remains - is it proper way to handle all exceptions occurred in Task.Run.

Comment: In .NET 4.0, exceptions raised in Task.Run have to be handled, or at least observed.  Two main patterns are either to put a `Try..Catch` block inside the Task.Run, or to check the result of the run by checking `Task.IsFaulted` (such as in a `.ContinueWith()` block).  In .NET 4.5, using the Await will allow exceptions to properly be brought back to the originating thread.

Comment: In a case where you start a Task.Run for a procedure that doesn't return a result, if there's an unhandled exception in the Task, it could bring down the whole application (at least it does in Windows Forms), because exceptions are not allowed to be unhandled in background threads.

Answer (score 0):

try this program and see if you still get breaking..

its working for me

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().TimerCallback();
    }

    public Task<string> ReadSensorsAsync(string cell)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if(cell == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
            return cell;
        });
    }

    public Task<string> RecordReadingAsync(IEnumerable<string> cell)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return string.Join(",", cell);
        });
    }

    public async void TimerCallback()
    {
        try
        {
            var tasksRead = new string[] { "1", null, "3" }.Select(s => ReadSensorsAsync(s));
            var taskRecordResult = await RecordReadingAsync(await Task.WhenAll(tasksRead));
            Debugger.Log(1, "test", taskRecordResult);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //catches here
            Debugger.Log(1, "test", e.Message ?? e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```